# How to open a video when the notification comes on phone without userclick? android

Tags: android, push-notification

My server is sending me a video URL in push notification, how to play that video without any user click (in a defaualt video player or web browser)

Please let me know if its possible or not.
Thank you.

Comment: u can startActivity once u get the notification.

Comment: without user click on notification video open????

Answer (score 0):

PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage can help you find the entry activity.

```
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: but the app is not open. App is fully destroyed. and how to open app when notification comes from server without user click

Comment: if u wan to load the url in browser try this one.  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Your URL"));
startActivity(browserIntent);

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcast component for it,after recieving video URL just broadcast that url and recieve it in onrecieve().And register the broadcast reciever in the activity in which you want to play video.

Comment: but the app is not open. i want to play it without clicking on the notification. like how watsapp call comes without any interaction.

Comment: PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.helloworld");
launchIntent.putExtra("some_data", "value");
context.startActivity(launchIntent);

Comment: put above code in on recieve notification and pass your URl to launcher activity and set a check  in onCreate(), like if URL is not null then start desired activity

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Your URL")); 
    startActivity(browserIntent);
   }
```